# conceptnet api documentation for /wn/ part of the URI

Tags: machine-learning

for url http://api.conceptnet.io/c/en/music/n/wn/communication

`/c/en/music/n` is explained the doc (https://github.com/commonsense/conceptnet5/wiki/URI-hierarchy) as:

"the initial /c to make it a concept, a part that indicates its language (usingthe BCP 47 language code for that language), and a part with the concept text. An optional fourth component gives the part of speech (as a single letter, following the convention of WordNet)."

But couldn't find documentation for the part `/wn/communication`. Could you point to the documentation for this or explain this part of URI .. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the finer-grained word sense information that was added in ConceptNet 5.7. WordNet defines "music" in the topic area of "communication". We keep this information in the word sense. The idea is to distinguish WordNet senses, but not to make the extremely fine distinctions that WordNet makes.

I didn't describe it on the "URI Hierarchy" page yet, sorry about that. It's described in the changelog for now: https://github.com/commonsense/conceptnet5/wiki/Changelog

"music" is a tricky example, because WordNet has finely-distinguished senses of it that appear to be in different WordNet topic areas, even though they all seem to relate to the same meaning. Its different senses are listed in topic areas including "communication", "act", and even "music" itself.